# How to join/connect two list in python?

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

I have two time-data pairs:

```
datedat1 = numpy.array([ pandas.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 
29), periods=5), 0.1 * numpy.arange(5)]).T
datedat2 = numpy.array([ pandas.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 
30), periods=7),  100 * numpy.arange(7)]).T
```

I want to connect `datedat1` and `datedat2` to get one long time-data pair. So I try:

```
(numpy.array([datedat1,datedat2])).flatten()
```

However, the `flatten()` didn't work. It just returns `(numpy.array([datedat1,datedat2]))`, a nested list. I want to get this

```
array([[Timestamp('2015-01-29 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.0],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.1],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.2],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.30000000000000004],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0.4],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00', freq='D'), 0],
   [Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00', freq='D'), 100],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), 200],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00', freq='D'), 300],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00', freq='D'), 400],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00', freq='D'), 500],
   [Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00', freq='D'), 600]], dtype=object)
```

What should I do?

Comment: `np.vstack((datedat1, datedat2))`

Comment: Try some of these: [Joining Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)